# lists:map(lists:sum,[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3]) is not allowed. Instead of list:sum there must be a fun?

Tags: erlang

Why is the following not allowed:

```
156> lists:map(lists:sum,[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3]).                       
* 1: illegal expression
```

, and when I make a fun around `lists:sum`, it is allowed:

```
162> lists:map(fun (L)->lists:sum(L)end,[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3]]).
[10,6]
```

?

Answer (score 4):

[@spkhaira answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53980098/1017941) is correct, reasoning behind this syntax decision is that in Erlang functions and variables occupies different namespaces, it is similar to Lisps 2. This is mostly because of 2 reasons:

- Erlang is dynamically typed language
- Functions in Erlang are defined by 2 values: it's name and arity (amount of arguments)

With these 2 properties we cannot deduce what "version" of the function you want to call, that is why you need to use `/N`. What about `fun` prefix? It is just needed for parser to differentiate between `erlang:'/'` (aka division) and `/N` that is used for defining arity.

Answer (score 3):

Try this -

```
lists:map(fun lists:sum/1,[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3]]).
```

Comment: That is what I found out too. Why must there be a fun? That is my question.

Comment: This is how it works in a functional language like Elixir. You need to pass a function that gets applied on each element of the list. In other languages you may use a block (i.e. Ruby) or a defacto iteration syntax (think for-loops in Java)